# Recall DynamoDB with Alexa query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create a skill with Alexa to read data from my DynamoDB table using either the scan or query function (or both).

The columns in my table are date, time and film name.

I'm new to this but I've managed to link my Lambda function to Alexa. I have also created a separate Lambda function that will recall data from my table when i configure test events, so when I input a specific date it will recall the corresponding film and time. However now I want to implement this into Alexa and am not sure how.

Here is my current code

```js
console.log('Loading function');

var AWSregion = 'us-east-1';  // us-east-1
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dclient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var getItems = (event, context, callback)=>{
    
    dclient.get(event.params,(error,data)=>{
        if(error){
            callback(null,"error occurerd");
        }
        else{
            callback(null,data);
        }
    });
};

exports.handler = getItems;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {

        var request = event.request;

        if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
            context.succeed(buildResponse({
                speechText: "Welcome to H.S.S.M.I skill, what would you like to find",
                repromptText: "I repeat, Welcome to my skill, what would you like to find",
                endSession: false
            }));
        }
        else if (request.type === "IntentRequest") {
            let options = {};         


            if (request.intent.name === "cinema") {
            } else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.StopIntent" || request.intent.name === "AMAZON.CancelIntent") {
                options.speechText = "ok, good bye.";
                options.endSession = true;
                context.succeed(buildResponse(options));
            }
             else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.HelpIntent") {
                options.speechText = "My skill will read your table depending on what is asked. For example, you can ask what about a specific date. Please refer to skill description for all possible utterences.";
                options.repromptText = "What is the data sign you want to know  about today? If you want to exit from my  skill please say stop or cancel.";
                options.endSession = false;
                context.succeed(buildResponse(options));
            }
            else {
                context.fail("Unknown Intent");
            }
        }

        else if (request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
            options.endSession = true;
            context.succeed();
        }
        else {
            context.fail("Unknown Intent type");
        }




    } catch (e) {

    }


};

function buildResponse(options) {
    var response = {
        version: "1.0",
        response: {
            outputSpeech: {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.speechText}</prosody></speak>`
            },

            shouldEndSession: options.endSession
        }
    };

    if (options.repromptText) {
        response.response.reprompt = {
            outputSpeech: {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.repromptText}</prosody></speak>`
            }
        };
    }

    return response;
}

function readDynamoItem(params, callback) {
    
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({region: AWSregion});
    var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
    console.log('reading item from DynamoDB table');

    dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else{
            console.log(data); // successful response
            callback(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    //Get item by key
    docClient.get(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

            callback(data.Item.message);  // this particular row has an attribute called message

        }
    });

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And here is my DBHandler

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region: "'us-east-1'"
});

let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var table = "Cinema";

let getItems = (Id,callback) => {   
  
    var params = {
        TableName: "cinema",
        Key: {
            "date": "2018-01-04",
            "filmname": "rugrats"
        }
    };

    docClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
        callback(err, data);
    });

};
module.exports = {
    getItems
};
```

I can launch the app and I have a Lambda function that works on its own when I configure the test event to find a movie from a certain date but I cannot get it to work with Alexa.

Can anyone help me or indicate where I'm going wrong

UPDATE*************

Here is how my intent schema is setup

```js
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "sincedate",
          "type": "AMAZON.DATE"
        }
      ],
      "intent": "date"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.CancelIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.StopIntent"
    },
    {
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "sincedate",
          "type": "AMAZON.DATE"
        }
      ],
      "intent": "cinema"
    },
    {
      "intent": "MyIntent"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part 1 - Permissions

One possible reason why you may not be able to read from DynamoDB in your skill is because of permissions.

You should double check the IAM role that you assigned to your skill lambda to make sure that it has permissions to read from DynamoDB.

Some references:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/using-identity-based-policies.html
- https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-an-aws-lambda-function.html#define-new-role

### Part 2 - The actual Skill handler Lambda

I re-read your question and I'm confused about the part where you talk about setting up a second Lambda to read data from Dynamo. You shouldn't have two Lambda functions - just one that will handle requests from Alexa and in that function you should return your response to Alexa, after making a call to Dynamo.

Now, to the specifics. In your first code snippet, you have:

```
exports.handler = getItems;

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // here you have your handler to handle alexa responses 
}
```

One thing that stands out immediately is that you are first setting the handler to `getItems` and then resetting back to the handler that is supposed to respond to the Alexa.

The other thing that I'm guessing is happening is that sometimes the skill works, like when you first launch it, and probably if you say Help but in other cases it doesn't, like when you send it the "cinema" intent.

This is because the entry point from the Alexa request to your skill is the `exports.handler` which is basically defined as a function with three parameters (it's like the void main(int argc,char *argv[]) of a c program).

The first parameter - `event` is the input to your skill. Alexa will supply information here such as the request type, if it's an intent, the intent name, session information etc.

The second and third parameters - `context` and `callback` are what you use to return control from your lambda function, depending on the node runtime. For Note v4 and newer, you use callback, for older versions you use context.

You can use something like this to send a success response back:

```
if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
     context.succeed("successful response message");
} else {
     callback(null, "successful response message");
}
```

And something like this to send a failure response

```
if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
     context.fail("failure response message");
} else {
     callback("failure response message", null);
}
```

Putting it all together, here's a basic Lambda handler that always responds to your skill invocations:

```
function sendResponse(context, callback, responseOptions) {
  if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    context.succeed(buildResponse(responseOptions));
  } else {
    callback(null, buildResponse(responseOptions));
  }
}

function buildResponse(options) {
  var alexaResponse = {
    version: "1.0",
    response: {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.output}</prosody></speak>`
      },
      shouldEndSession: options.endSession
    }
  };
  if (options.repromptText) {
    alexaResponse.response.reprompt = {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.reprompt}</prosody></speak>`
      }
    };
  }
  return alexaResponse;
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    var request = event.request;
    if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
        output: "welcome to my skill. what do you want to find?",
        endSession: false
      });
    }
    else if (request.type === "IntentRequest") {
      let options = {};         
      if (request.intent.name === "cinema") {
        // this is where we will wire up the dynamo call
        // for now, just send a simple response and end the session
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "cinema not implemented yet!",
          endSession: true
        });
      } else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.StopIntent" || request.intent.name === "AMAZON.CancelIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "ok. good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
      else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.HelpIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "you can ask me about films",
          reprompt: "what can I help you with?"
          endSession: false
        });
      }
      else {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! Good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
    }
    else if (request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, ""); // no response needed
    }
    else {
      // un unexpected request type received.. just say I don't know..
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! Good bye!",
          endSession: true
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // handle the error by logging it and sending back an failure
    console.log('Unexpected error occurred in the skill handler!', e);
    if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
       context.fail("Unexpected error");
    } else {
       callback("Unexpected error");
    }
  }
};
```

Getting to this point, the skill should be functional and it should be able to handle all your requests. Assuming that you have configured your interaction model correctly and that the `cinema` intent gets sent to your skill, then here's how you can use dynamo client to respond with data from a table.

```
var AWSregion = 'us-east-1';  // us-east-1
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

let handleCinemaIntent = (context, callback) => {    
  let params = {
    TableName: "cinema",
    Key: {
        "date": "2018-01-04",
        "filmname": "rugrats"
    }
  };
  dbClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       // failed to read from table for some reason..
       console.log('failed to load data item:\n' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       // let skill tell the user that it couldn't find the data 
       sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "the data could not be loaded from Dynamo",
          endSession: true
       });
    } else {
       console.log('loaded data item:\n' + JSON.stringify(data.Item, null, 2))
       // assuming the item has an attribute called "message"..
       sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: data.Item.message,
          endSession: true
       });
    }
  });
};


function sendResponse(context, callback, responseOptions) {
  if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    context.succeed(buildResponse(responseOptions));
  } else {
    callback(null, buildResponse(responseOptions));
  }
}

function buildResponse(options) {
  var alexaResponse = {
    version: "1.0",
    response: {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.output}</prosody></speak>`
      },
      shouldEndSession: options.endSession
    }
  };
  if (options.repromptText) {
    alexaResponse.response.reprompt = {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.reprompt}</prosody></speak>`
      }
    };
  }
  return alexaResponse;
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    var request = event.request;
    if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
        output: "welcome to my skill. what do you want to find?",
        endSession: false
      });
    }
    else if (request.type === "IntentRequest") {
      let options = {};         
      if (request.intent.name === "cinema") {
        handleCinemaIntent(context, callback);
      } else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.StopIntent" || request.intent.name === "AMAZON.CancelIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "ok. good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
      else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.HelpIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "you can ask me about films",
          reprompt: "what can I help you with?"
          endSession: false
        });
      }
      else {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! Good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
    }
    else if (request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, ""); // no response needed
    }
    else {
      // un unexpected request type received.. just say I don't know..
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! Good bye!",
          endSession: true
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // handle the error by logging it and sending back an failure
    console.log('Unexpected error occurred in the skill handler!', e);
    if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
       context.fail("Unexpected error");
    } else {
       callback("Unexpected error");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi I believe my permissions are fine, I think its my code thats wrong but i dont know where im going wrong

Comment: if it helps, the current response i get from my skill is 'The response is invalid'

Comment: ok - I've updated the answer - it should hopefully make things a bit clearer

Comment: thanks for your reply, and thank you for taking your time to explain things, helped me learn alot. Your code has helped but im currently getting 'the data could not be loaded from Dynamo' as my response, is there anyway i can rectify this?

Comment: Glad the answer helped (perhaps consider an upvote ;) and yes, if you are getting an error loading data it means the callback from the handleCinemaIntent returns an err object so you have to look at the log for the lambda in CloudWatch to see exactly what the error is. Either comment here or add another question

Comment: thanks, already have done but 'Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score' and I will check this now and comment here thank you for your help

Comment: I cant seem to find a log error in cloud watch. Could it be something to do with my interaction model?

Comment: nevermind its update now, is this what you wanted. Is this what you wanted? Ill post it in the next comment

Comment: State Details:The current state of the alarm: OK, ALARM or INSUFFICIENT_DATA. Includes information about when it entered this state and why.State changed to INSUFFICIENT DATA at 2018/03/05. Reason: Insufficient Data: 5 datapoints were unknown.
Description:The description provided when the alarm was created or modified.
Threshold:The condition in which the alarm will go to the ALARM state.ConsumedReadCapacityUnits >= 240 for 5 datapoints within 5 minutes
Actions:The actions that will occur when the alarm changes state.
In ALARM:

Comment: Send message to topic "dynamodb" Send message to topic: "dynamodb" (Warning: this alarm is not configured to notify. Please modify this alarm and add an email address.)

Comment: no, you should be able to go to the Lambda console for your skill, and open the Monitoring tab, then click on "View in CloudWatch" which should take you to a cloudwatch logs page that shows the console log messages from your skill; there will be one there that is logged from the "handleCinemaIntent" that shows what the problem is with the get item from dynamo

Comment: Hi is this what I should be looking for? 2018-03-05T11:04:51.322Z 1a3ec8c3-0c75-4921-9f73-6484c3e4bab1 Unexpected error occurred in the skill handler! TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at exports.handler.e (/var/task/index.js:67:16)

Comment: yes, something like that, though I suspect that error was from a different invocation - perhaps you were testing the lambda invocation? that doesn't seem to be an actual skill invocation - the error is telling you that the event object did not actually contain a "request" parameter though all alexa skill requests do, so that lambda invocation must not be from an actual skill request

Comment: you should look in the logs for one that says something like: "failed to load data item" and then see what the error is; most likely it is about the structure of that data item.. but I can't say without the error message

Comment: Hi this is all I can find at the moment. Ill try again today. I've just clicked on the dynamodb section under my lambda function and it says 'Last processing result: PROBLEM: Function call failed'

Comment: Hi Mike, i've gone ahead and added my intent schema too incase this is what could be causing the issue.

Comment: I've also just found this 
2018-03-07T12:17:33.188Z 837c1935-2201-11e8-954c-9f5848878a0b failed to load data item:
{
    "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
    "code": "ValidationException",
    "time": "2018-03-07T12:17:33.188Z",
    "requestId": "GOEV2364PM9BASV2PG0A3NUN4JVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 2.3846124370334842

Comment: That is exactly the log you need! The error message explains that the parameters passed to the DynamoDb client get command are incorrect - in particular apparently the key schema is incorrect, meaning it doesn’t match the key schema you used when created the table; if you look at the key being passed in the get it sends a “date” and a “filmname” but apparently those are not right. You should take a look at the table definition in the DynamoDB console and then double theck those parameters to the get in the handleCinemaIntent function

Comment: Make sure to check the spelling of “date” and “filmname” in the table schema and make sure they are both string. Make sure that the schema has both a partition key and a range key..

Comment: thank you, I had a read online and read i should only define my partition key. I've done this and it works correctly for one of my items in my table, but anything else i search it gives me the same response as the one item that works. Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: I do, but I feel like this is now a very different question/problem than what you had originally started with. I encourage you to post a new question specific to the dynamo part. This way, answering it will benefit the whole community (plus the answer requires more than what I can fit in a comment). After you post the question feel free to add a comment to it and mention me and I'll try to answer that as well.

Comment: thanks, you're right, hence why i've accepted your answer! I have gone ahead and added another post.